# How to modify Wildfly/JBoss config using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss, wildfly

I'm migrating a Spring MVC web application to a  Spring Boot. The build (maven) generates a .war file then I upload it to Wildfly Server. I used to be able to upload large file now it doesn't work.

On the old way, using Spring MVC, I updated the Wildfly' server config itself `/standalone/configuration/standalone-full.xml` which **no longer work** after switching to Spring Boot

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="304857600" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
```

So the config above says allow posting files up to ~300MB (see the 304857600)

How to modify Wildfly/JBoss config using Spring Boot?

My google search was redirected here by some user comment, but still unsure how to do it in Spring Boot
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Undertow+subsystem+configuration

I'm on:

- JDK 1.8
- spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar
- Wildfly 10.

Comment: This helped me - https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2018/08/06/how-to-deploy-a-spring-boot-war-in-wildfly-jboss/

Comment: @JaisAnkit it doesn't help my case. I managed to get things running between Spring Boot and  Wildfly. I think I just need to change Wildfly config from Spring boot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpringBoot ask to setup these two additional config parameter to control the size limits of file upload/post request. I am certain that's causing the limitation in your case, if your Wildfly server is configured to not limit it.

```
#Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size
#Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size
```

***Reference***: SpringBoot [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) for file upload feature.

Comment: It's a progress @amith-kumar
`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760`
Now it is showing `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Comment: Application is running outofmemory, increase the heap size `-Xms, -Xmx`.

Comment: I already have that my wildfly server's `/Users/pringadi/dev/apps/servers/.wildfly-jboss/bin/standalone.conf` there is `JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx1024m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"`. The limitation issue just happen after Spring Boot ignores Wildfly configs values.

Comment: I will say go ahead & increase further. I also noticed you have a marginal difference between Xms & Xmx, which doesn't benefit you anything but give performance bottleneck. Please read this [post](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/149559?_sscc=t) to understand why it's a good idea to keep it same.